# Import Mongodb to CSV - removing duplicates

Tags: python, mongodb, import, duplicates

I am importing data from Mongo into a CSV file. The import consists of "timestamp" and "text" for each JSON Document.

The documents:

```
{ 
name: ..., 
size: ..., 
timestamp: ISODate("2013-01-09T21:04:12Z"), 
data: { text:..., place:...},
other: ...
}
```

The code:

```
with open(output, 'w') as fp:
   for r in db.hello.find(fields=['text', 'timestamp']):
       print >>fp, '"%s","%s"' % (r['text'], r['timestamp'].strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

I would like to remove duplicates (some Mongo docs have the same text), and I would like to keep the first instance (with regards to the time) intact. Is it possible to remove these dupes as I import?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use the aggregation framework and group on both fields.

Comment: I believe `ensureIndex({text}, {dropDups:true})` will keep the first found intact. That could be one way to go, import all then strip dups after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to maintain a map (dictionary) to maintain (text, timestamp) pairs. The 'text' is the key, so there won't be any duplicates. I will assume the order of reading is not guaranteed to return the oldest timestamp first. In that case you will have to make 2 passes-- once for reading and later one pass for writing.

```
textmap = {}

def  insert(text, ts):
    global textmap
    if  text in textmap: 
        textmap[text] = min(ts, textmap[text])
    else:
        textmap[text] = ts

for r in db.hello.find(fields=['text', 'timestamp']):
    insert(r['text'], r['timestamp'])

for text in textmap:
   print >>fp, text, textmap[text]  # with whatever format desired.
```

At the end, you can also easily convert the dictionary into list of tuples, in case you want to sort the results using timestamp before printing, for example.
(See [Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) )

Answer (score 2):

I would use a set to store the hashes of the data, and check for duplicates.  Something like this:

```
import md5

hashes = set()
with open(output, 'w') as fp:
   for r in db.hello.find(fields=['text', 'timestamp']):
       digest = md5.new(r['text']).digest()
       if digest in hashes:
            # It's a duplicate!
            continue
       else:
            hashes.add(digest)
       print >>fp, '"%s","%s"' % (r['text'], r['timestamp'].strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

It's worth noting that you could use the text field directly, but for larger text fields storing just the hash is much more memory efficient.

Comment: There could be collision in the hash. i.e. 2 different text can hash to same value. In that case some entries will be missed in the output.

Comment: But incredibly unlikely, even if MD5 is not collision-resistant.  If the OP is worried of that he can store the text field in the set without hashing them, or use a better hash function, such as SHA-3.